# cannot get folder from src/main/resources Java project Maven

Tags: java, eclipse

I try to loop over all files in a certain folder in my resources (I added this folder myself in eclipse by doing new->folder). Whatever I try it keeps giving a null exception on the line where I try to get the folder. As I need to loop over its content getting it as a stream or something won't work. 
I tried many approaches, but for example these two gave me the error:

```
File folder = new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("schematics").getPath());
```

This wrapped inside a try catch did also not work:

```
File folder = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("schematics").toURI());
```

My file structure (class where I try to access the schematics is HeavenStructureManager's initialiser):

[image]

EDIT
This project is a minecraft plugin, bundled to a jar by maven and run by the spigotmc minecraft jar. Their api provides a function getResource() but that gives a InputStream. As I would like to dynamically get all files inside a folder that does not work for me.
I unpacked my jar file to check where the schematic is, and it looked like this:
[image]

Comment: Are you running the code in Eclipse or in unit tests? The current directory may also be the project directory. So, it would be src/main/resources/schematics or something.

Comment: @Serge It is a minecraft plugin. I compile it through maven as a jar, but it is run by spigot's minecraft server launcher

Comment: Can you see what is the output of System.getProperty("user.dir") (current directory)?

Comment: @Serge that gives `/Users/Eric/Desktop/Test Server` which is the path my server's spigot main jar is in. That is indeed completely off, as I am trying to get a resource from inside of my plugin's jar (jar of my plugin located at  `/Users/Eric/Desktop/Test Server\plugins\Heaven-0.1.jar`.

Comment: Heaven-0.1.jar on the class path of the running app?

Comment: @Serge I think so (not really sure what it means). Heaven-0.1.jar is my project, whose structure I showed above. The resources files are inside that jar as well. I never run it directly though, I run the spigot.jar (minecraft server jar) which in turn loads the plugins (I think at least)

Comment: @Serge I edited my question to show where in the jar my resource is, does that help?

Comment: Just added a code example to retrieve contents of a jar file (S: below). Hope it gives an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a code example to iterate through the contents of a jar file, list them and write the contents to a new file.

Current run directory: .

Jar file directory: ./plugins/org.alloytools.alloy.dist.jar

Output directory: ./unzipped

```
package com.serge;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarInputStream;

public class JarFileReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File file = new File("plugins/org.alloytools.alloy.dist.jar");
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            JarInputStream jarInputStream = new JarInputStream(fileInputStream);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = null;

            File unzippedDir = new File("unziped");

            while(jarInputStream.getNextEntry() != null) {
                JarEntry entry = jarInputStream.getNextJarEntry();

                // list the contents of the jar file 
                System.out.println(entry.toString());

                // write contents of a file within the jar file to a new file
                if("help/Nav.html".equals(entry.getName())) {
                    new File(unzippedDir + "/" + entry.getName().substring(0, entry.getName().indexOf("/"))).mkdir();
                    File unzippedFile = new File(unzippedDir + "/" + entry.getName());
                    unzippedFile.createNewFile();
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(unzippedFile);

                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                    int length = 0;

                    while((length = jarInputStream.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, length);   
                    }
                }
            }

            outputStream.close();
            jarInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I however simply accepted the fact that I could only get files as a stream (managed to change the way I used the API) and have a list which tells what the filenames are. Your code probably works too but for stability/simplicity I will keep what I have now. I will accept your answer because you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try using an absolute path:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/schematics")
```

When you use the getResource method, getResource will try to find the resource relative to the class package. Therefore, when you use the path ("schematics"), in reality, you are referring to the file at the location [resources]/com/ericdebouwer/heaven/schematics. By using a leading / getResource treats it as an absolute path.

Comment: This gives me a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI` is not hierarchical error. I did this btw: `File schematicFolder = new File(getClass().getResource("/schematics").toURI());` How should I fix that?

Comment: Use getResourceAsStream instead of trying to load it as a file.

Comment: @Deadron As i said in my question that is not an option. I need to loop over the folder's content and the library I am using requires an actual file object.

Comment: Just added a code example to retrieve contents of a jar file (S: below). Hope it gives an idea.